# Firebase y Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, textview

Tengo una duda, estoy intentando obtener valores de *Firebase* y quiero imprimirlos en un *textView* en *Android Studio* el problema es que cuando corro la aplicación y navego a la parte en donde se supone que tiene que aparecer la información pasan como 5 o 10 segundos y se crashea la aplicación.

Los datos que quiero obtener son los siguientes: *humedad y temperatura*.

[image: Datos]

Pero la aplicación cuando se supone se debería de mostrar los datos, dura unos segundos y se crashea.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity5Temperatura extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textDatos;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity5_temperatura);

        textDatos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView53);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //Validar si el objeto al cual hacemos referencia existe en la base de datos
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    //snapshot es el objeto persona
                   //humidity es el atributo hijo del cual se quiere extraer la informacion
                   double humedad = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("humidity").getValue().toString());
                   double temp = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("temp").getValue().toString());
                   textDatos.setText(humedad+" "+ temp);
                    
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede ver en la imagen que los valores de humidity y temp no están dentro de users.
No puedo responder a tu pregunta porque en la imagen no se ve que nodo es el padre de humidity y temp. Igualmente te dejo un enlace a un proyecto que encontré y que funciona muy bien https://github.com/rcAndroidTutorials/example-firebase/tree/master

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero recuerda realizar respuestas en base a [answer],saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes en el mDatabase.child("Users")
Ya que los datos que quieres estan en mDatabase.
Me refiero, que te sobre el child("Users")

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero recuerda realizar respuestas en base a [answer],saludos.